# How to find application that wants access to private key

Tags: permissions, ssh, gnome-keyring

For a few days now I get following pop up whenever I start the computer and sometimes randomly during the session:

[image: Enter password to unlock private key dialog]

The censored part contains my e-mail address. How can I find out *which* application this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnome keyring uses these files listed with `ls`:

```
ls /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-* ~/.config/autostart
```

where any of them that has

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

set. Those are all suspects for this popup.

Networkmanager is a likely culprit for fetching the wireless password. So is `ssh` if you have that installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, as a relative newbie I couldn't have asked for a better answer! It seems it must have been a Nextcloud client. Do you know why the application is not identified in these pop-ups?

Comment: Nope I do not know that.